# Javascript Chosen plugin initialisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

I use templating engine and send html and javascript through ajax. I receive the folowing

```
<select id="categorylvl1" name='product[catlvl1]' data-rel="chosen" style="display:none;">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#categorylvl1").chosen(); //Dont work
    $("#categorylvl1").trigger("liszt:updated"); //Dont work either
</script>
```

It seems chosen initialize at loading and i can find where or how to trigger it on new select.

Nwm, im dumb, i didnt put

```
$("#categorylvl1").chosen();
```

in right folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your JS in `$(document).ready()` like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Here is javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#categorylvl1").chosen(); //Dont work
    $("#categorylvl1").trigger("liszt:updated"); //Dont work either
});
</script>
```

Comment: Tryed, didnt work :( Strange thing, is despite i have style="display:none;" it still showing the select somehow.Without data-rel="chosen" select dont appear.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Also, what's with the `liszt:updated` part? Isn't that a typo?

Comment: I dont have errors, liszt:updated is neded when you manually add stuff to your select for plugin to update.

Comment: Try removing the `display: none` part, I've seen problems with it.

Comment: Doesnt work, this code works on main page, but when i press next, it alter the old one with exact same code, but chosen dont work :(

Comment: Haha sorry im so dumb, i have diffeerent folders like step1, step2 and so on, i alter changes in step1 folder, but receive data from another, its work now ^^